# Laravel: Axios not sending data in request

Tags: laravel, axios

I have an `axios` get request that makes a call to a `laravel` api. However, I have an issue where the `params` are not being passed to the server. I have written a test function to check that everything is working.

```
axios.get('/api/myCall',{
        params: {
            id: 1,
            name: 'loser',
        }
    }).then(response => {
        console.log('response', response);

    })
```

Server side

```
public function myCall(Request $request) {
    return response()->json($request->input());
}
```

Response

```
{ "data": [], "status": 200, "statusText": "OK", "headers": { "access-control-allow-origin": "*", "cache-control": "no-cache, private", "connection": "close", "content-type": "application/json", "date": "Thu, 19 Aug 2021 18:46:23 GMT, Thu, 19 Aug 2021 18:46:23 GMT", "host": "xxxx", "x-powered-by": "PHP/7.4.3", "x-ratelimit-limit": "60", "x-ratelimit-remaining": "49" },... and other stuff }
```

As you can see the data field is empty

However when I test it on another server that is running the same configuration, I get:

```
{ "data": { "id": "1", "name": "loser" }, "status": 200, "statusText": "OK", "headers": { "access-control-allow-origin": "*", "cache-control": "no-cache, private", "connection": "close", "content-type": "application/json", "date": "Thu, 19 Aug 2021 18:46:23 GMT, Thu, 19 Aug 2021 18:46:23 GMT", "host": "xxxx", "x-powered-by": "PHP/7.4.3", "x-ratelimit-limit": "60", "x-ratelimit-remaining": "49" },... and other stuff }
```

Any ideas as to why there is no data being sent in one case?

Laravel: 8.42

Axios: 0.21.1

Edit: It works if I switch to `Post` method, however I think this is not the answer to my original question.

Comment: Maybe don't send the entire `$request` object in `json()`; it's a pretty massive object that likely won't get parsed to JSON cleanly. Try `return response()->json($request->input());` and see if that returns the correct input data.

Comment: Hi Tim, I have tried what you suggested but it still does not work. I don't think that that was the issue since, it works on another similar server. I have edited my question with your change

Comment: Interesting. There shouldn't be any special requirements for a `GET` request. Can you access this in a browser? I.e. if you navigate to `http://localhost:8000/api/myCall?id=1&name=loser`, do you see a JSON object? And using a browser, you should be able to do `dd($request->input());` for debugging too.

Comment: @TimLewis The myCall function requires Request parameter. If you just type in the url, it won't have one right?

Comment: `Request $request` is "injected" into the `myCall` method and uses Query String parameters, like `?id=1&name=loser`, or `FormData` parameters, like in the case of a `POST` request. Typing into the browser manually using `?id=1&name=loser` is a `GET` request with a valid Query String, so it should return data via `$request->input()`

Comment: If you look at my screenshot, I generated that from `http://localhost:8000/test?id=1&name=loser`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D277L.png, from the Controller method `public function test(Request $request){ dd($request->input(), $request->all());`, and the Route: `Route::get('/test', [TestController::class, 'test']);`

Comment: You say that you get the correct/expected result when you run it on another server with the same configuration. If that's the case, either the two servers aren't actually using the same configuration, or you are calling them differently. Either way there is more info needed to answer your question.

Comment: @TimLewis the dumps are correct one server (like your picture) and just empty on the other .ie  [] []

Comment: @hansn they are being called the same on both severs (the same code is pushed to both). The problem I have is I don't know what possible differences could lead to this so I don't know where to start looking on what is different between the two servers

Comment: If the code is the same on the frontend and backend in both cases, at least you know where not to look. I would start by comparing the `$request` variable in both cases. You know the input is missing in one case, but what else is different? Hopefully that'll give you a clue to what's going wrong :)

Comment: @hansn they are identical except for the data, date and X-XSRF-TOKEN fields